haproxy not consistently retrying with retry-on and redispatch
I've configured haproxy (3.0.5 running as a container on ECS/fargate) with retries > 0 to redispatch on errors. It's working sometimes, but not every time. It's only retrying with redispatch about 20% of the time.
I have it configured (I think) to:

retry on most retryable errors
retry 2 times
redispatch on every retry

global
    log stdout len 4096 format raw local0
    maxconn 2000
    tune.bufsize 262144
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    stats socket ipv4@127.0.0.1:9999  level admin  expose-fd listeners
    lua-load /tmp/haproxy_files/static_404.lua

defaults all
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    timeout client  50s

defaults backends from all
    option httpchk
    http-response del-header server

resolvers awsdns
     nameserver dns1 10.10.0.2:53
     accepted_payload_size 8192 # allow larger DNS payloads

listen stats from all
    bind :8080
    mode http
    http-request use-service prometheus-exporter if { path /metrics }
    monitor-uri /haproxy-stats-health
    stats enable  # Enable stats page
    stats hide-version  # Hide HAProxy version
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics  # Title text for popup window
    stats uri /haproxy-stats  # Stats URI

#############################################################
# main endpoint for the services on the ECS cluster
frontend mh-serverless from all
    bind *:8080
    # simple health check for frontend LB to haproxy
    monitor-uri /haproxy-health

    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor
    http-request add-header x-forwarded-proto https
    http-request add-header x-forwarded-port 443
    capture request header x-amzn-trace-id len 256
    capture request header x-forwarded-for len 256
    capture request header host len 256
    capture request header referer len 256
    capture request header user-agent len 40
    capture request header x-custom-header len 5
    # use JSON lines format for easier parsing in cloudwatch and datadog
    log-format '{"timestamp":"%[date(0,ms),ms_ltime(%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N%z)]","x-amzn-trace-id":"%[capture.req.hdr(0)]","x-forwarded-for":"%[capture.req.hdr(1)]","http_method":"%HM","uri_path":"%HPO","query_args":"%HQ","http_version":"%HV","http_status_code":"%ST","termination-state":"%ts","latency":%Ta,"response_length":%B,"referer":"%[capture.req.hdr(3)]","backend_name":"%b","host":"meridianlink-prod","service":"haproxy-router","backend":{"name":"%b","concurrent_connections":%bc,"source_ip":"%bi","source_port":"%bp","queue":%bq},"bytes":{"read":%B,"uploaded":%U},"captured_headers":{"request":{"x-forwarded-for":"%[capture.req.hdr(1)]","host":"%[capture.req.hdr(2)]","referer":"%[capture.req.hdr(3)]","user-agent":"%[capture.req.hdr(4)]","x-custom-header":"%[capture.req.hdr(5)]"},"response":"%hs"},"client":{"ip":"%ci","port":"%cp"},"frontend":{"name":"%f","concurrent_connections":%fc,"ip":"%fi","port":"%fp","name_transport":"%ft","log_counter":%lc},"hostname":"%H","http":{"method":"%HM","request_uri_without_query_string":"%HP","request_uri_query_string":"%HQ","request_uri":"%HU","version":"%HV","status_code":%ST,"request":"%r","retries":%rc},"process_concurrent_connections":%ac,"request_counter":%rt,"server":{"name":"%s","concurrent_connections":%sc,"ip":"%si","port":"%sp","queue":%sq},"timers":{"tr":"%tr","Ta":%Ta,"Tc":%Tc,"Td":%Td,"Th":%Th,"Ti":%Ti,"Tq":%Tq,"TR":%TR,"Tr":%Tr,"Tt":%Tt,"Tw":%Tw}}'

    use_backend clientA-app if { path_beg /api/clientA/app }
    use_backend clientB-app if { path_beg /api/clientB/app }
    use_backend clientC-app if { path_beg /api/clientC/app }
    # ..... and so on ...

    default_backend static_404

#############################################################

backend clientA-app from backends
    http-check send meth GET uri /health
    balance roundrobin
    # how long to wait for a successful connection
    timeout connect 3s
    # how long to wait for a response to an http request (7s is just slightly longer than the typical FIST penalty)
    timeout server 7s
    # how long to wait for a response to health check
    timeout check 14s
    # total number of retries
    # this value is appropriate when max number of tasks will be 3
    retries 2
    # redispatch on every retry
    option redispatch 1
    # explicitly list types of errors in order to not include 4XX, 500, 501, etc.
    retry-on 0rtt-rejected response-timeout junk-response empty-response conn-failure 502 503 504
    server-template svc 3 clientA-app.ecs-cluster-prod.local:5000 check inter 15s fall 5 rise 1 resolvers awsdns init-addr none

backend clientB-app from backends
    http-check send meth GET uri /health
    balance roundrobin
    # how long to wait for a successful connection
    timeout connect 3s
    # how long to wait for a response to an http request (7s is just slightly longer than the typical FIST penalty)
    timeout server 7s
    # how long to wait for a response to health check
    timeout check 14s
    # total number of retries
    # this value is appropriate when max number of tasks will be 3
    retries 2
    # redispatch on every retry
    option redispatch 1
    # explicitly list types of errors in order to not include 4XX, 500, 501, etc.
    retry-on 0rtt-rejected response-timeout junk-response empty-response conn-failure 502 503 504
    server-template svc 3 clientB-app.ecs-cluster-prod.local:5000 check inter 15s fall 5 rise 1 resolvers awsdns init-addr none

backend clientC-app from backends
    http-check send meth GET uri /health
    balance roundrobin
    # how long to wait for a successful connection
    timeout connect 3s
    # how long to wait for a response to an http request (7s is just slightly longer than the typical FIST penalty)
    timeout server 7s
    # how long to wait for a response to health check
    timeout check 14s
    # total number of retries
    # this value is appropriate when max number of tasks will be 3
    retries 2
    # redispatch on every retry
    option redispatch 1
    # explicitly list types of errors in order to not include 4XX, 500, 501, etc.
    retry-on 0rtt-rejected response-timeout junk-response empty-response conn-failure 502 503 504
    server-template svc 3 clientC-app.ecs-cluster-prod.local:5000 check inter 15s fall 5 rise 1 resolvers awsdns init-addr none

#############################################################

backend static_404 from all
    http-request use-service lua.static_404

However, these are the logs that I'm seeing:
#timestamp,hostname,server(%b),uri_path(%HPO),status_code(%ST),timers.Ta(%Ta),read(%B),uploaded(%U),retries(%rc),termination-state(%ts)
2024-10-13T17:37:00.916,hostA.com,clientA-app.ecs-cluster-prod.local:5000,/api/clientA/app,504,7068,198,46427,0,sH
2024-10-13T17:28:19.880,hostA.com,clientB-app.ecs-cluster-prod.local:5000,/api/clientB/app,504,21003,198,50147,+2,sH
2024-10-13T17:28:08.873,hostA.com,clientC-app.ecs-cluster-prod.local:5000,/api/clientC/app,504,7011,198,50245,0,sH
2024-10-13T12:30:24.284,hostA.com,clientC-app.ecs-cluster-prod.local:5000,/api/clientC/app,504,7000,198,47781,0,sH
2024-10-13T03:19:21.817,hostA.com,clientB-app.ecs-cluster-prod.local:5000,/api/clientB/app,504,7003,198,41351,0,sH
2024-10-13T02:40:15.121,hostA.com,clientA-app.ecs-cluster-prod.local:5000,/api/clientA/app,504,21010,198,53686,+2,sH
2024-10-13T02:39:20.349,hostA.com,clientC-app.ecs-cluster-prod.local:5000,/api/clientC/app,504,7002,198,67650,0,sH

Notice that sometimes there will be retries, and the timers.Ta is consistent with the total number of retries, but most of the time haproxy is not retrying. This is not only happening on 504s; it's happening on 503s as well. Not sure on other other types since those are a little harder to induce.
I've tried playing with the tune.bufsize parameter since our reqest payloads can be quite large (max up to 1MB recently). I've set it to 256K for now since that covers the 95%-ile. Most of the payloads are greater than the default 16K so initially we were getting almost zero retries.
I've played with various retry-on settings (like all-retryable-errors) but same thing.
Based on the config above, I'm expecting haproxy to retry on all of the errors listed in retry-on and for all request payloads < 256K, but that's not what I'm seeing.
